# What's the need of a polished surface in a plane mirror?

Tags: reflection

In a plane mirror, my textbook tells me that in a plane mirror one surface is polished and the other is silvered. If light gets reflected from the silvered surface, why does the polished surface have to be there?

Comment: Which textbook, which page?

Comment: Etching of glass makes it rough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather you are describing a mirror that is built like

light -> | glass | metal

And your question is, why the glass is polished on the outer side? To suppress unwanted reflections/scattering of the light. If you have rough or textured surface you cannot look through it unhindered and will have additional reflections. This is how your brain is able to **see** that a surface is rough: there are uneven surface normals leading to bright and dark spots. You don't want any of this in a mirror

Comment: So basically, to make the surface smooth for regular reflection.